# After Ubuntu 16.04 update some programs were lost

Tags: 16.04

I use Ubuntu 16.04. A couple of days ago I found that several programs, particularly R, KRDC, PlayOnLinux, cannot be launched and the OS does not see them at all. I looked at the installed packages with `apt list --installed` but also did not find any traces of them.

I repeated the installation of KRDC and it starts to work and founds all previous settings. However I do not think that this is a right way, since for R I'll need to re-install a lot of packages and dependencies.

I suspect that it was happened after one of automatic updates. But I did not launch those programs for a week or two and now I don't know how to detect what was wrong and how to fix this. Could you advice me something?

UPDATE.

I found partially broken Software center. Software & updates menu did not work. Re-installation fixed this. Probably there are more damaged software.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade process disables third-party ppas. If the programs you are missing came from this kind of source, you will have to re-enable the ppas and re-install the programs.

Comment: 1) KRDC and R (r-base) is from the main Ubuntu repo, but nevertheless they disappeared. 2) I see the third-party rstudio and virtual-box ppas in the `source.list` and at least Virtual box works, but RStudio cannot find R and thus does not start. 3) I meant just ordinary automatic updates which come daily not the upgrade from the older Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

TRY TO INSERT THE REPOSITORY FILES INTO SOURCES.LIST FILE USING SUDO TO RESOLVE 
USE THIS COMMANDS TO RESOLVE THE PROBLEM WITH PLAY ON LINUX

wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install playonlinux